# WordPress RSS feed using FishPig for Magento 2

Tags: magento2, fishpig

Is it possible to display an RSS feed using FishPig for Magento 2? The official WordPress documentation for RSS feed (https://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Feeds) doesn't seem to apply in this case; is this built-in functionality that I can take advantage of, or will I need to extend the module and build out a custom feed?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

To display RSS feeds, you will need the [Shortcodes and Widgets add-on module](https://fishpig.co.uk/magento/wordpress-integration/shortcodes-widgets/). This will get all feeds of all types working automatically. It will also allow you to use any shortcode based WordPress plugin (page builders, form plugins, sliders etc).